# Ethernet connection drops intermittently in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 13.04, ethernet, realtek

During the last couple of days, I have noticed that my ethernet connection drops about once every 5 minutes. The connection has worked for a number of years without problems before that. I am running a 64-bit Ubuntu 13.04.

The ethernet controller is a Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 01).

This is the output from lscpi -v:

```
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 01)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
I/O ports at c000 [size=256]
Memory at f9000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
[virtual] Expansion ROM at fa800000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: r8169
```